# identifying pairwise groups from dictionary

Tags: python, hash-map

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
masterdict = {'a':['b','c','d','e'],
         'b':['c','d','e'],
         'c':['d','e'],
         'd':['e']
         'e':[]}
```

where the list has all the values that are 'compatible' with the key and vice-versa. Since the dictionary is non-redundant, repeated compatiblities are not reported in the dictionary. For eg. 'e' is compatible with 'a','b','c' and 'd' but masterdict['e'] is empty since it is reported in the other lists. I would like to identify all groups of elements, such that all the elements are mutually compatible. Hence for the masterdict given above, the solution would be `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e'], ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]`. Not showing lists of smaller size.

```
masterdict = {'a':['b','d','e'],
         'b':['c','d'],
         'c':['e'],
         'd':['e'],
         'e':[] }
```

then the solution would be `[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'd', 'e']]`. I did write a recursive function to do this, but it is slow for larger dictionaries (len(list) > 1000). The code is given below. I would like some suggestions on how to write a faster version, maybe using itertools or some other module. Thanks alot

```
import sys
import os

def recursive_finder(p1,list1,masterdict,d,ans):
        # if lenght of d is more than 2, store that list in ans
        if len(d) >2 :
                ans.append(d)
        nextlist = []
        # if lenght of list is 0, do not do anythin
        if len(list1) == 0:
                pass
        else:
                other = []
                for i in list1:
                        if i in masterdict[p1]:
                                new = []
                                new.extend(d)
                                new.append(i)
                                other.append(new)
                                nextlist.append(i)
                for i in range(len(nextlist)):
                        p1 = nextlist[i]
                        dnew = other[i]
                        recursive_finder(p1,nextlist[i+1:],masterdict,dnew,ans)

masterdict = {'a':['b','d','e'],
         'b':['c','d'],
         'c':['e'],
         'd':['e'],
         'e':[] }

final = []
ans = []
for mainkey in masterdict:
        if len(masterdict[mainkey]) > 1:
                for i in range(len(masterdict[mainkey])):
                        p1 = masterdict[mainkey][i]
                        recursive_finder(p1,masterdict[mainkey][i+1:],masterdict,[mainkey,p1],ans)

print(ans)
```

Comment: The problem can be formulated as [finding cliques in graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). Finding maximal cliques is an NP-Complete problem. You could consider using third-party libraries such as [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/clique.html) for the task.

Answer (score 1):

## Indentation

You should use four (4) spaces for indentation, not eight (8).

## Logic

This

```
if len(list1) == 0:
    pass
else:
```

should be changed to

```
if list:
    ... code here ...
```

This removes the need for the `else`, as you instead check if the list contains anything. Check out the [Python Docs on Truth Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

## Enumerate

This

```
for mainkey in masterdict:
    if len(masterdict[mainkey]) > 1:
        for i in range(len(masterdict[mainkey])):
            p1 = masterdict[mainkey][i]
            recursive_finder(p1,masterdict[mainkey][i+1:],masterdict,[mainkey,p1],ans)
```

can be changed to this

```
for mainkey in masterdict:
    if len(masterdict[mainkey]) > 1:
        for i, value in enumerate(masterdict[mainkey]):
            p1 = value
            recursive_finder(p1,masterdict[mainkey][i+1:],masterdict,[mainkey,p1],ans)
```

Use enumerate since you are using both the index and the value.

Comment: The `for`-loop can be changed to `for mainkey, mainvalue in masterdict.items()` to avoid multiple references to `masterdict[mainkey]`.